# Reduce vector of structs based on percentage change

Tags: rust

I have a struct with two U256 integers:

```
struct FromTo {
  from_amount: U256,
  to_amount: U256
}
```

I need to reduce a `Vec<FromTo>` to a single `FromTo` struct based on the percentage change of `from_amount` and `to_amount` (or some other way to rank the integers).

I have the following `from_amount` and `to_amount` values (integers smaller for the sake of readability)

```
let from_to = vec![
  FromTo {
    from_amount: 100,
    to_amount: 200,
  },
  FromTo {
    from_amount: 50,
    to_amount: 120,
  },
  FromTo {
    from_amount: 200,
    to_amount: 100,
  },
  FromTo {
    from_amount: 120,
    to_amount: 50,
  }
]
```

The `Vec` should be reduced to `FromTo { from_amount: 50, to_amount: 120 }` as the percentage change is the highest (140%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Iterator::max_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by) method to return the largest item in a sequence according to a given comparison closure:

```
fn max_pct_diff<'a>(data: impl IntoIterator<Item=&'a FromTo>)
    -> Option<&'a FromTo>
{
    data.into_iter().max_by(|a, b| {
        let (a1, a2) = a.to_amount.div_mod(a.from_amount);
        let (b1, b2) = b.to_amount.div_mod(b.from_amount);

        a1.cmp(&b1).then_with(||
            // To compare the remainders without a conversion to floating
            // point, we can use the relational equivalence:
            //
            // a/b > c/d
            //
            // has the same result as
            //
            // a*d > b*c

            (a2 * b.from_amount).cmp(&(b2 * a.from_amount))
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any hints on how to convert a U256 to f32 ?

Comment: @James Updated my code to work with U256 directly, by way of `U256::div_mod()`

Comment: @James Updated again to handle the remainders properly.